# How do I make multiline hilighter on draft-js?

Tags: draftjs

Now I make markdown highlighter.

Highlight inline is not so difficult. I use CompositeDecorator to rewrite text. https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-decorators.html

But I can't use multiline syntax (for example, codeblock). By default, newline becomes next block and decorator is handled by block to block.

Below image is example of my implementation. I can't decorate codeblock syntax.

[image]

How do I make multiline highlighter on draft-js?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what 'Highlight' style you want. Mostly the inline style should be enough if you just want some color or font size. check the [color](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/color/color.html) example.

While for block style, you need a custom CSS class and map the block to your class, refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-block-styling.html#content).

Comment: I can implement highlighting text in content-block (like that color example) but detecting code block syntax from raw text and decorating it is difficult yet.

Comment: I not known you need detecting the code block from raw text. If you apply the code syntax by detecting raw text, how a new block (without any raw text) can tell you it is a 'code block'?

Answer (score 0):

I found work around. Detecting markdown codeblock by dand on blockRendererFn.

````
// use blockRedererFn
<Editor
  blockRendererFn={(block) => blockRenderer(block, this.state.editorState)}
  editorState={this.state.editorState}
/>;

// detect code block and add fontFamily: monospace
// Example
//
// ```
// here
// ```
function blockRenderer(contentBlock, editorState) {
  const type = contentBlock.getType();
  if (type === "unstyled") {
    const allText = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText();
    const allCount = countCodeBlockHeader(allText);
    if (allCount > 0 && allCount % 2 === 0) {
      const contentText = contentBlock.getText();
      const [before, after] = allText.split(contentText);
      const beforeCount = countCodeBlockHeader(before);
      const afterCount = countCodeBlockHeader(after);
      if (beforeCount % 2 === 1) {
        if (afterCount % 2 === 1) {
          return {
            component: (_props) => {
              return <code style={{
                fontFamily: "monospace",
                direction: "ltr",
                unicodeBidi: "bidi-override",
              }}>{contentText}</code>;
            },
            editable: true
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function countCodeBlockHeader(text) {
  return text
  .split("\n")
  .filter(l => l.match(new RegExp("^(```)")))
  .length;
}
````

but it's dirty.